# Cannot serve_site() using blogdown in RStudio

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I'm using [this](https://www.dsquintana.blog/free-website-in-r-easy/) tutorial to try and develop a website using blogdown. I get to the point of serving the site locally ( `blogdown::serve_site()` ) at which point in both the RStudio inline preview and my browser I get the error 'ERROR: cannot change working directory'.

It happens whether I use the 'academic' or any other theme, and I have never been able to get it to work at all.

I am using RStudio v1.2.1335, with R v3.4.4, in Linux Mint 18.1, and blogdown::hugo_version() returns '0.16'

Searches haven't been useful: this seems to identify the problem, but I can't seem to identify anything to change that allows me to serve even the example site

Any pointers would be gratefully received!

Comment: Problem solved after much sweating - I ignored the install_hugo() step altogether and compiled hugo (using the 'extended' binary) from the hugo website. Works perfectly after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Hugo version is way too low. Currently the hugo-academic theme requires [at least Hugo 0.55](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/blob/64cceae0995ff7ba3f362fa699f0e341b14bbca1/theme.toml#L6). If you install [the development version](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown) of **blogdown**, it will [automatically update Hugo](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/391) when the version is not sufficient for a theme. With your current version of **blogdown**, you can also update Hugo by yourself: `blogdown::update_hugo()`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'd spotted the hugo version was very old - I think installing this via blogdown might be the issue. I used `update_hugo()` but `hugo_version()` still returned '0.16'. 

I then tried `blogdown::install_hugo(version = '0.55.6', force = TRUE)`, which seemed to run ok, but then `hugo_version()` returned '0.16' again, and I got a string of error messages and pop-ups. The messages in the RStudio console read 'Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database '/home/viridis/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/blogdown/help/blogdown.rdb' is corrupt'

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: When in doubt, restart R :)